# mixed up POST values in Perl script

Tags: forms, perl, post, cgi

I need to send POST values to server url, and I'm using this code:

```
$ogone_ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
$ogone_response = $ogone_ua->post("http://server.url/", {
'ACCEPTURL' => 'http://server.url2',
'AMOUNT' => '1000',
'CURRENCY' => 'USD',
'LANGUAGE' => 'en_US',
'ORDERID' => '20130105220939',
'PSPID' => 'vukasin',
'SHASIGN' => '6AEE128943C7C896A6449FF7C2CE702222995B7F'
} );
```

but server receives:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
TE: deflate,gzip;q=0.3
Connection: TE, close
Host: athlon.herrpan.com:2389
User-Agent: SSL-AirKiosk/1.0
Content-Length: 206
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

LANGUAGE=en_US&ACCEPTURL=http%3A%2F%2Fserver.url2&SHASIGN=6AEE128943C7C896A6449FF7C2CE702222995B7F&CURRENCY=USD&AMOUNT=1000&PSPID=vukasin&ORDERID=20130105220939
```

Why it is not in order? The bank API needs POST values to be sorted, just like in code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hashes don't have an inherent order, so the order is lost before `->post` is even called. However, [`POST`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3a%3aRequest%3a%3aCommon) (to which `->post` passes its args) also accepts an array reference.

```
->post("http://server.url/", [
   ACCEPTURL => 'http://server.url2',
   AMOUNT    => '1000',
   CURRENCY  => 'USD',
   LANGUAGE  => 'en_US',
   ORDERID   => '20130105220939',
   PSPID     => 'vukasin',
   SHASIGN   => '6AEE128943C7C896A6449FF7C2CE702222995B7F',
]);
```

Comment: You are *fast* -- I was typing up an inferior response to this and your answer appeared. Good work!

Comment: @ikegami doesn't mess around. :)